# Android RelativeLayout Background Picture from Gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I have a problem to set background image for `RelativeLayout`. details problem : 
- I have `RelativeLayout` and `Button` in my UI. when button clicked then showing Gallery's intent. choose 1 picture from that gallery and i want to set that picture as RelativeLayout background.

I can call the intent for gallery, but i'm still fail to set that picture as RelativeLayout background. please help me

**Edit** (here's my example code to set ImageView from Gallery intent):

```
final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            //img.setImageResource(Intent.);
            Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    //Integer selectedImageUri;
    //Integer[] bg = {selectedImageUri};
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                      ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
```

---

So how to set that picture not as image for ImageView, *but as RelativeLayout background*

Comment: please paste your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After picking the picture from gallery, you can set the picture like this-

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);

            RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
            Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            relative.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where can i put the picture from gallery if i use your code ? i'm li'l don't understand about bitmap :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting drawable resource then you can set background of relative layout using that drawable like the following.

```
  RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
  relativeLayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
  RelativeLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

Hope it will help.